# date validation giving error "strftime' is not defined"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to validate date with two different input form.I don't know i ma doing wrong.

forms.py

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    manual_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y','%d/%m/%Y'],
                      widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'size':'15','id':'datepicker'},format=["%m/%d/%Y","%d/%m/%Y"]))
    manual_time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%H:%M','%I:%M %p'],
                      widget=forms.TimeInput(attrs={'size':'8','class':'time_field'},format=["%H:%M","%I:%M %p"]))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        manual_date = cleaned_data.get('manual_date')
        manual_time = cleaned_data.get('manual_time')

        if manual_date != strftime('%d %b %Y') and strftime('%b %d %Y'):
            raise ValidationError('Enter a valid date')
        return cleaned_data
```

template:

```
{{ ReportForm.manual_date }}{{ ReportForm.manual_date.errors }}
{{ ReportForm.manual_time }}{{ ReportForm.manual_time.errors }}
```

I am getting this error "global name `'strftime' is not defined"`,i surely don't know the method i did is right.

I want to validate the date and time for both format.If user select `dd/mm/yyyy` format it should validate in that format and if the selected date is `mm/dd/yyyy` it should validate date in that format.Please guide me how to implement in clean() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` is a method found on datetime objects to convert them to strings.

Your error is quite simple: it's not defined. If you opened a python shell and typed in Royal, would you expect an error? Same thing.

---

By the time `clean` is called, the datetime object has already been constructed. There is no input type validation at this point - it's already been converted to a datetime.

Comment: Actually royal, i now see you are checking for date format. The input_formats should auto validate that.

Answer (score 0):

while raising error use forms.ValidationError  not just ValidationError see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/